# Different permalink url for new posts?

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about permalinks.

I want to change posts permalink line /postname-post-id.html
But i dont want to change old posts permalinks ? Because google already indexed 200k links for this web page. I just want to use new permalink options for next / future posts.

Is this possible or not ? If it is what should i do ? Thank you so much.

Old permalinks

```
domain.tld/postname.html
```

New Permalinks

```
domain.tld/postname-post_id.html
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. You can, however, change the permalink for new articles and *redirect* your old articles to the new permalink, thereby keeping your old permalink accessible. Using a 301 (permanent) redirect, [some say](http://flippa.com/blog/guide-to-redirects-for-seo/), does not affect SEO/Google rankings and from my own experience I have little reason to doubt that.

You can use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalinks-migration-plugin-for-wordpress/) to redirect old urls, so your new posts have new urls and so do your old ones, but your old ones are also still accessible via the old links.

Comment: Hmm thank you @V.H but i need really want to this. I will goole it again. Thanks.